# What kind of encoding is root.tex from ieeeconf using?

Tags: input-encodings, ieeeconf

I [downloaded the IEEEconf document class](https://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/tex.php) (the [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeeconf?lang=de) version seems to be several versions behind). I have problems to figure out the encoding of the file `root.tex` in the `ieeeconf.zip` file. All quotation marks show up as `Ò` or `Ó`:

```
This electronic document is a ÒliveÓ template.
```

Any idea what encoding this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file is encoded with the [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) character encoding:

- [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) encodes a `“` as `D2` and a `”` as `D3`
- [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) decodes `D2` as `Ò` and `D3` as `Ó`

Comment: that's crazy (but right:-) You should report it to them to fix that, they should use standard tex markup `\`\`..''` or use utf-8 or (at least and the worst option) declare the mac encoding with `inputenc`/